# Can anyone help me in recording script using recording controller in jmeter?

Tags: automation, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, automation-testing

I have done till creation of proxy sever.Facing some socket broken issue on running the scripts in firefox

When i perform some actions everything is working then some error occurs

also explain what is jmeter tree model and jmeternode is?

```
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
//  recordingController recordingcontroller=new recordingController("testrecorder",RecordController.class);
//  RecordingController rc= (RecordingController) recordingcontroller.buildTestElement();


        RecordingController rc = new RecordingController();
        GenericController gc = new GenericController();
        rc.initialize();

        gc.addTestElement(rc);

        LoopController loopController = new LoopController();
        loopController.setLoops(1);
        loopController.setFirst(true);
        loopController.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, LoopController.class.getName());
        loopController.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, LoopControlPanel.class.getName());
        loopController.initialize();

        rc.addTestElement(loopController);
        ThreadGroup threadGroup = new ThreadGroup();
        threadGroup.setName("Thread-Group");
        threadGroup.setSamplerController(loopController);


        ProxyControl proxyController = new ProxyControl();
//  proxyController.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, ProxyControl.class.getName());
//  proxyController.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, ProxyControlGui.class.getName());
        proxyController.setName("Proxy Recorder");
        proxyController.setPort(4444);
//  threadGroup.setSamplerController(rc);
//           proxyController.setSamplerTypeName("SAMPLER_TYPE_JAVA_SAMPLER");


        TestPlan testPlan = new TestPlan("My_Test_Plan");
        testPlan.addTestElement(threadGroup);
        testPlan.addTestElement(proxyController);


        JMeterTreeModel jtm = new JMeterTreeModel();
        proxyController.setNonGuiTreeModel(jtm);
        JMeterTreeNode node = new JMeterTreeNode(proxyController,jtm);

//           JMeterTreeNode node=new JMeterTreeNode();
        proxyController.setTarget(node);
//        proxyController.setCaptureHttpHeaders(true);
//        proxyController.setUseKeepAlive(true);
//        proxyController.setGroupingMode(4);

        proxyController.setCaptureHttpHeaders(true);
        proxyController.setProxyPauseHTTPSample("10000");
        proxyController.setSamplerFollowRedirects(true);
        proxyController.setSslDomains("www.geeksforgeeks.org");
        proxyController.startProxy();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think non-GUI proxy recording is something you can achieve with vanilla JMeter, if you have to automate the recording process you will have to go for desktop applications automation solutions like [Appium](https://appium.io/docs/en/drivers/windows/) or [LDTP](https://ldtp.freedesktop.org/wiki/)

If you need to record a JMeter script using Firefox on a system which doesn't have GUI I can think of following approaches:

1. Use [Proxy2JMX Converter](https://gettaurus.org/docs/Proxy2JMX/) module of [Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/) tool
2. Use [BlazeMeter Proxy Recorder](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000271458-Creating-the-Proxy-Recorder-Creating-the-Proxy-Recorder) (by the way it has nice feature of exporting recorded scenarios in ["SmartJMX" mode with automatic detection and correlation of dynamic parameters](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-cut-your-jmeter-scripting-time-80))